# session variables for out of proc cause memory problems?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, session-variables

In my current `asp.net` application, i'm storing the `session variables` in the `SQL server`. If you specify `InProc`, then the session is kept in the server memory, but for `out of proc` (in my case), the session is kept in SQL server.

Is this really true? From what I read, with every request that needs session access (basically every page request) will deserialize the session from db and save it back once the request completes. This means that the values will be kept on the web server once it is retreived. How is this different from the `InProc` then?

For `Out of Proc`, does it only retreive the one session variable when that is requested for? Otherwise, it sounds to me like it is the same as `InProc`. What am I missing.

Comment: Note that if you do need out of proc session management (due to farm issues/process issues/etc.) then you can also sue the StateServer mode (which is stored in memory by a special service running on a server somewhere.)

Comment: yes, but my point mainly was to say the server does have the session variables in its memory for other modes although only for the request duration.

Comment: Well, sure. Your code is executing on a server node in an IIS worker process. At some point, that process needs the data in memory. How else could it work?

Comment: just wasn't sure if all the data was in memory at the same time or only the requested one(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this really true?

Yes, it's true.

> From what I read, with every request that needs session access
>   (basically every page request) will deserialize the session from db
>   and save it back once the request completes. This means that the
>   values will be kept on the web server once it is retreived. How is
>   this different from the InProc then?

Values are stored in memory only for the duration of the HTTP request. In the beginning of the request they are loaded from SQL Server and at the end of the request they are saved into SQL Server. This is different than InProc where values are kept into memory between requests. And because different requests (from the same user) could be served by different nodes in your server farm, using SQL Server guarantees that all nodes of the farm will share the same session values.

Comment: assuming the server gets a lot of requests per minute, wouldn't it cause the same effect. For the duration of the request, the server memory will contain the session variables. I would think in case of a site that has too much traffic, out of proc adds more overhead. Yes, if you have multiple nodes, you have no option.

Comment: @AlexJ, values are loaded per session. So if your server gets lots of traffic from different users each request will fetch its corresponding session values from SQL Server. And of course that SQLState adds overhead compared to InProc. But it's the most robust solution for web farms. You could also use StateServer in a web farm where session is stored in memory of a special server and is faster compared to SQLState but less robust and reliable.